# Signature for this request is not valid. - Binance API

Tags: python, binance, python-binance

I'm getting the following error when using the binance-connector with python:

```
 "price": 20348.91, "quantity": 4.914e-05, "side": "BUY", "symbol": "BTCUSDT", "timeInForce": "GTC", "timestamp": 1696014956799, "type": "LIMIT", "signature": "..."}}
{'error': {'code': -1022, 'msg': 'Signature for this request is not valid.'}
```

This is my python code (partially):

```py
        qty_to_buy: float  = self.USER_TRADE_BALANCE/current_bid_price
        qty_to_buy = float("{0:.8f}".format(qty_to_buy)) # only 8 digits allowed after the comma

        self.currentlyBuying = True
        self.buying_bid_price = current_bid_price

        self.binance_client.new_order(
            symbol=self.TRADE_SYMBOL,
            side="BUY",
            type="LIMIT",
            timeInForce="GTC",
            quantity=qty_to_buy,
            price=current_bid_price,
        )
```

qty to buy has 8 digits after the comma, there's nothing wrong about it since I'm respecting the ticker rules. I'm trying to buy at the current bid price.

I'm using the binance testnet where I've built a new API key (and secret), so they are both correct.

***What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?***.

***I've tried*** making a new API key twice and nothing happened, I've increased recvWindow to 50000 and it still didn't work. What else am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is `qty_to_buy` supposed to be the _number of shares_ to buy?  If so, then it makes no sense for it to be a float, and it **especially** makes no sense for it to be such a small number, around 0.00004.  Why are you trying to place an order to buy 0.00004 shares of something?

Comment: yes, qty to buy is the number of shares to buy. It is a float because I don't want to buy a full BTC for 25k, I'm trying to buy 1 USDT, which is 0.00.. sth BTC. I'm buying a small amount of BTC because I'm building a bot that makes a couple dozen trades a minute. The quantity that I'm buying is irrelevant, I'm doing this on the binance testnet anyways. The problem that I have is the 'signature' thing

Comment: Looking at a few binance API [examples](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#module-binance.client), they all use whole numbers for `quantity`.  But I couldn't find any api function named `new_order()`.

Comment: I was assuming that the signature error was a side effect of using a wrong data type for the `quantity` input item.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: I'm using the binance connector: https://binance-connector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.spot.trade.html?highlight=new_Order#binance.spot.trade.new_order. Quantity is a float, so is quantity in the official API https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#new-order-trade

Answer (score 0):

Pass the qty as string, it should work.

e.g.

```py
self.binance_client.new_order(
            symbol=self.TRADE_SYMBOL,
            side="BUY",
            type="LIMIT",
            timeInForce="GTC",
            quantity='0.00004914',
            price=current_bid_price,
        )
```